# Combinatorics - Shortest route on grid with a blockade

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose a grid starts at position $(0,0)$ and extends up and to the right. A shortest route along streets from $(0,0)$ to $(i,j)$ is $i+j$ units long, going $i$ blocks east and $j$ blocks north. Suppose that the block between $(k,l)$ and $(k+1,l)$ is closed, where $k<i$ and $l \le j$. How many shortest routes are there from $(0,0)$ to $(i,j)$?

Without the closed street the answer is clearly $i+j\choose i$ or equivalently $i+j \choose j$. with the blockade I took the number of ways to get to position $(k,l)$ and multiplied this by the number of ways to go from $(k+1,l)$ to $(i,j)$ and subtracted this from original answer.$$ {i+j\choose i} - {k+l \choose k}*{i+j-((k+1)+l) \choose i-(k+1)}$$

I'm wondering if this approach is right and if there is and easier representation? Also can you extend this to a number of closed routes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this approach is right. I don't think there's any easier representation. More closed routes would just lead to more terms in the product (and an application of the inclusion-exclusion principle).